# ROSjava VisualizationView

Tags: ros, laser-scan, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

have anybody working example of VisualizationView, because the tutorial map_viewer doesn't work. Now I try use VisualizationView for display map and laser scan, but I am not yet successful. In RViz is all working well, and communication should by OK, in rxgraph are all arrows right connected.

My code:

> VisualPanel = (VisualizationView) findViewById(R.id.visualization);
> ...
> CameraControlLayer cameraControlLayer =  new CameraControlLayer(this, nodeMainExecutor.getScheduledExecutorService());
> VisualPanel.addLayer(cameraControlLayer);
> OccupancyGridLayer Map = new OccupancyGridLayer("map");
>
> VisualPanel.addLayer(Map);
> VisualPanel.addLayer(new LaserScanLayer("scan"));
> ...
> nodeMainExecutor.execute(VisualPanel, nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("android/map_view")

Thanks for any advice

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54522/rosjava-visualizationview/) by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The visualization view works successfully on some of my android devices, but not on my tablet, Nexus7.(I should say that I rewrote the source code a little to use OccupancyGridLayer as you did.)
I don't know the reason, but you should try your application on another kind of android.
In addition, I wonder if you set the camera frame to a right position by using VisualizationView.getCamera().jumpToFrame() method.

---

Originally posted by [KazutoMurase](https://answers.ros.org/users/2505/kazutomurase/) with karma: 116 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1